# Error while converting mysql query to postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

The following query works in MySQL:

```
SELECT
  f.created_date as time_sec
  ,sum(f.value) as value
  , date_format( f.created_date , '%a') as metric
FROM ck_view_fills as f
GROUP BY date_format(f.created_date, '%a' )
```

I have migrated my database to PostgreSQL and I am now converting my queries to match. My naive conversion looks like this:

```
SELECT
  f.created_date as time_sec
  ,sum(f.value) as value
  , to_char( f.created_date , "D") as metric
FROM ck_view_fills as f
GROUP BY to_char( f.created_date , "D")
```

This query is not accepted and the error message produced by PostgreSQL is the following:

> Error in query (7): ERROR: column "f.created_date" must appear in the
>   GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 2:
>   f.created_date as time_sec

As far as I can tell f.created_date is indeed used in the group by clause. I have also seen examples using this very syntax. So what is the cause of this error and how do I get around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres is correct. In fact, your query would fail with the most recent versions of MySQL as well -- using the default settings.

Just use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT MIN(f.created_date) as time_sec,
       SUM(f.value) as value
       TO_CHAR(f.created_date, 'D') as metric
FROM ck_view_fills f
GROUP BY to_char(f.created_date , 'D');
```

You should have used a similar construct in MySQL (regarding `MIN()` -- or `MAX()`).